# Loop after Grouped JSON properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

https://jsfiddle.net/MauroBros/f1j0qepm/28/#&togetherjs=qedN5gf7SF

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
var values = [
{"aname":"account1", "pname":"pname1", "vname":"vname1", "vid":"xxx"},
{"aname":"account2", "pname":"pname2", "vname":"vname2", "vid":"xxx"},
{"aname":"account2", "pname":"pname2", "vname":"vname3", "vid":"xxx"},
{"aname":"account2", "pname":"pname3", "vname":"vname1", "vid":"xxx"},
]
```

I grouped the "vname" by "pname"

```
var groups = {};

 $.each(values, function(key, values) {
 
    if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(values.pname)) {
        groups[values.pname] = {
            aname : values.aname,
            aid : values.aname,
            pname : values.pname,
            pid : values.pid,           
            vid: [],         
            vname: []
        };
    }
    groups[values.pname].vname.push({
        vname: values.vname,
        vid: values.vid
    });
});
```

Now I'm trying to loop:

```
   $.each(groups, function(key, groups) {   
     $('#provider-accounts')
         .append($("<optgroup></optgroup>")
         .attr("label","  " + groups.aname)) 
     
         .append($("<optgroup></optgroup>")
         .attr("label","    " + groups.pname))

         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",groups.vid)
         .text("      " + groups.vname[0].vname)); 

  });
```

ISSUE

The output doesn't return all the options "vname" but only the first one.
How can I insert a loop in the loop. Something like this:

```
       $.each(groups, function(key, groups) {   
         $('#provider-accounts')
             .append($("<optgroup></optgroup>")
             .attr("label","  " + groups.aname)) 
         
             .append($("<optgroup></optgroup>")
             .attr("label","    " + groups.pname))

for (var i = 0; i < groups.vname[0].vname.length; i++) {    

             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value",groups.vid)
             .text("      " + groups.vname[0].vname[i])); 
}    
      });
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to chain it all into one chain I would create a separate object for the  groups first. Then loop through the array and append the various options to the second group and finally append the groups to the select.

This seems to be easier to read also than the chained appends you are currently using

```
$.each(groups, function(key, groups) {
  var $group1 = $("<optgroup>").attr("label", "  " + groups.aname);
  var $group2 = $("<optgroup>").attr("label", "    " + groups.pname);

  groups.vname.forEach(function(el) {
    $group2.append(new Option(el.vname, el.vid));
  });

  $('#provider-accounts').append($group1, $group2);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

@charlietfl's answer does it, and I agree that it would make your code more readable. But if you're still interested if such looping is possible - yes it is. You can use Array `.map()` for this and append the resulting array of Option elements.

```
.append(
    groups.vname.map( vItem =>
        $("<option></option>")
           .attr("value",groups.vid)
           .text("      " + vItem.vname)
    ));
```

I tried to fork your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/b2yg5jvm/